# Creating a large number of entries in a SQL table efficiently

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-insert

I am building an RSS reader that notes (as Google Reader did) when posts are read. I have it working to the extent that as I scroll down, it marks posts as read by inserting rows into a "read articles" table that notes the item read (`ciid`), the user who read it (`uid`) and the date read (`dateRead`).

Now, I'm contemplating how to offer a "Mark All As Read" function. If there were only, say, 25 unread articles, that would be simple enough. I'd query the main article table for the 25 articles -- I have a subquery to determine which articles are unread -- unread by the current user, collect the `ciid`s that need to be marked as read and insert the new read entries. But, what if there are 20,000 entries unread? It seems rather inefficient to retrieve 20,000 unread entries, collect those `ciid`s and then send back to the MySQL server 20,000 insert commands.

Is there a more efficient way to do this, perhaps with a SQL query that handles all of this directly? If only one or two users is on the system, I'd guess my inefficient method wouldn't be a problem, but I'd like the system to scale relatively well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```
REPLACE INTO read_articles (uid, dateread, ciid) 
SELECT <user-id>, NOW(), id FROM articles
```

Where you must specify the user-id to be inserted. The REPLACE INTO will delete any existing dateread. If you do not want this behaviour, you could do this

```
INSERT INTO read_articles (uid, dateread, ciid) 
SELECT <user-id>, NOW(), id FROM articles
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE uid=uid;
```

However, I do not think the approach you are taking (storing read articles on a per-article basis) is scalable. When the user clicks *mark all*, you could store the datetime of that event in the users table. All articles older than the last mark-all-date is considered read.

Maybe you should only consider articles from the last 7 days in your table, ie. regularly delete read_articles records older than one week. All articles older than 7 days you just ignore (so actually you assume they have been read).

Comment: Thanks, @user1853955! This sounds like it would do the trick. I think you are right about article aging -- I need to think about how to best implement that. I'm considering deleting articles out of the database entirely, assuming they are of a certain age, unless the particular ciid only has a very small number of articles. I don't want to mark a per user "read all" because users can tag feeds and so the read all might only apply to "Technology" feeds and not "International News" feeds, for example.

Comment: I suppose I could mark a read all flag for each tag, although right now tags don't have any independent existence; they just exist as an attribute of the different feeds. Hmm...

Comment: You could store read articles per user, optionally with some timeout, without too much problems (assuming proper indexing). The problem is that your "read all" feature would add a lot of data to this table. I think a "last-read-all" date (for each tag) is a good idea.

Comment: That sounds easy enough to accomplish. Thanks for the great pointers, @apartridge!